# Remove "#comments" from dynamically loaded URLs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've got a problem where all the dynamic links on my homepage have "#comments" at the end, making it so when the user clicks their screen is annoyingly jolted down to the 'Comments' section each time rather than staying on top.

Example URL:

`https://example.com/441447279/amazing-art/#comments`

Is there a way to dynamically strip them of the 'comments' part via jQUery?

They're always the SECOND link in a unique class `<p class="g1-meta entry-meta entry-byline entry-byline-s entry-byline-with-avatar">`

so I was thinking something like

`var linkURL = $(".g1-meta.entry-meta.entry-byline.entry-byline-s.entry-byline-with-avatar").find("a").prop('href');`

but I don't know how to make it retrieve the SECOND link instead of the 1st.

And I don't know where to go from there... Help appreciated.

Comment: use something like: `var hrefString = hrefElement.getAttribute('href'); hrefString.replace('#comment',''); hrefElement.setAttribute('href', hrefString);`

Comment: For further help and snippet, please post a [reprex] with an example of a dynamically created document.

Comment: example of getting the element (no jQuery): `element = document.querySelector('[href*="/#comments"]');` or use `querySelectorAll` to get a list of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
//The key here is to use nth-of-type selector

$(".g1-meta.entry-meta.entry-byline.entry-byline-s.entry-byline-with-avatar").find("a:nth-of-type(2)").each(function(){
    let link = $(this).prop('href').replace('#comments','');
    $(this).prop('href',link)
})
```

Or without jQuery

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.g1-meta.entry-meta.entry-byline.entry-byline-with-avatar')).forEach(function(node){
    let anchorNode = node.querySelectorAll('a')[1];
    anchorNode.href= anchorNode.href.replace('#comments','');
})
```